# What is a convincing and useful real application of the Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, sampling, central-limit-theorem

I understand what the central limit theorem is about (ie. that the shape of the distribution of the sample means of any population)

Comment: You are hard to impress

Comment: It’s not clear what you consider AHA application. It’s like saying what’s the use of earth being round? We’d be perfectly fine with the flat one

Comment: Statistics and probability theory would be nothing like we know if CLT didn’t hold true. Anyhow, good luck finding someone willing to spend their time to convince you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you listed the stock market as an example, the price of a stock is bounded from below by zero and could be considered to follow a non-normal distribution.  You could model the price of a stock as an ARIMA time series and use the central limit theorem to construct a confidence interval for the mean of the process.  You could also use the central limit theorem to construct a prediction interval for future observed prices.

Pharmaceutical companies use the central limit theorem to construct confidence intervals around a treatment effect and use this inference to obtain approval from regulators so they can sell the treatment for a profit.

The central limit theorem is useful in non-normal settings for constructing tolerance limits for population percentiles.  Such tolerance limits are needed in manufacturing and quality control settings to ensure the vast majority of products produced meet minimum quality and safety standards.  These products can then be sold at a profit.

Comment: The CLT deals with a sum or average of observations and is useful when constructing an estimator and performing inference.  The miner might use the CLT to invert a hypothesis test and perform inference on the average amount of gold per kilo of soil.  The distribution of quantity of gold per kilo of soil would follow a non-normal distribution but might be well approximated by a normal distribution.  This is not an instance of the CLT, it is just a convenient approximation.  See for example the Poisson and Gamma distributions.

Comment: The miner may want to perform inference on percentiles (distribution) of gold quantity per kilo.  Some kilos in the grounds will have little gold, other kilos will have much more gold.  He could posit a model for the distribution of gold per kilo, estimate a percentile using many samples, and use the CLT to invert a hypothesis test and perform inference on the percentile.  This is analogous to the quality control example I provided.

Comment: Based on a sample he would estimate, say, that 90% of kilos have less than 1 ounce of gold.  Based on the CLT a 95% tolerance interval (CI for a percentile) would indicate, say, that with 95% confidence the true $90^{th}$ percentile for all the kilos in the entire grounds is between 0.91 and 1.1 ounces.

Comment: The CLT gives us an approximation to the sampling distribution of the sample mean.  It does not tell us the data generative process of the individual observational units, i.e. the distribution of gold quantity for all possible 1kg soil samples.

Answer (score 0):

A core discipline in statistics is inference; the process of using data to infer properties of an underlying distribution of probability, i.e. creating confidence intervals, p-values.

The use of the CLT is at the heart of hypothesis testing (at least in the frequentist setting), where you need to quantify how likely/unlikely an observed summary statistic is given some assumed model. Without CLT you would be unable to produce such inference which is at the core of sound decision making theory. Of course in some settings you do not need to rely on CLT for inferential results, such as in the Bayesian framework where you can do approximate inference on the exact posterior.

Comment: "the process of using data [**in a sample**] to infer properties [**in a target population**]"